# discord.py command is not found

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

the bot keeps giving me this error:

> Ignoring exception in command None:
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "rs" is not found

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime
from discord import client

print("holaaaaaa")
token = "token"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=("."))

contatore1 = 0
redstar = "@everyone Vorrei fare una rs "
partecipanti = "\n Partecipanti: "

support = "0/4"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(client.user, "ONLINE ","(ID ", client.user.id,")")

@commands.command()
async def rs(message):
    if message.channel.id == 605465213956915218:
        global redstar
        global contatore5
        global tag5
        global support5
        global partecipanti
        redstar = "@everyone Vorrei fare una " + message.channel.name
        tag5 = "\n" + message.author.mention
        contatore5 = 1
        if (contatore5 == 1):
            support5 = "1/4"
            await message.send(redstar + partecipanti + support5 + tag5)
    if (message.channel.id == 605465543134150657):
        global contatore6
        global tag6
        global support6
        redstar = "@everyone Vorrei fare una " + message.channel.name
        tag6 = "\n" + message.author.mention
        contatore6 = 1
        if (contatore6 == 1):
            support6 = "1/4"
            await message.send(redstar + partecipanti + support6 + tag6)

client.run(token)
```

Also, it should be noted that the on_ready event runs.
Any help is appreciated thanks :)

Comment: It has to be `client.command()` since this is not in a `Cog`, I guess. Thus, commands start with the `ctx` parameter. `message` is mostly used in events like `on_message`. To use `message` in a command, simply say `ctx.message`.

Comment: it doesn't have to be `@client.command` even if it's outside the cog, but `@client.command` does make it easier. if you for some reason want to make a command without using `@client.command` then you can just add `client.add_command(rs)` somewhere below the function and before `client.run`

Comment: If you read the source code you can see that [`@client.command` actually uses `client.add_command`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L1331-L1332)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can go on about fixing your problem.

- The one suggested by [Dominik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14449816/dominik) where you would need to change your `@commands.command()` to `@client.command()`. So like change

  ```py
  @commands.command()
  async def rs(message):
  ```

  to

  ```py
  @client.command()
  async def rs(message):
  ```
- Manually adding the command afterward using [bot.add_command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=add_command#discord.ext.commands.Bot.add_command). With this you would have to add

  ```py
  client.add_command(rs)
  ```

  somewhere below the command definition and above the client.run.

I personally suggest the first method since it's more concise.